# How to Mapping TPH in ownsmany

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, tph

I have three classes for abstract Payment.

```
public class CardPayment : Payment
{
    public CardPayment(Guid distributeId, Guid invoiceId, int userId, decimal amount, DateTime dateTime, long serialNumbner, long terminalNumber, long referenceNumber, DateTime bankDateTime) : base(distributeId, invoiceId, userId, amount, dateTime)
    public long SerialNumber { get;private set; }
    public long TerminalNumber { get; private set; }
    public long ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime BankDateTime { get; set; }
}

public  class Payment: EntityBase<Guid>
{
    public Guid DistributeId { get; private set; }
    public Guid InvoiceId { get; private set; }
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public  PaymentType Type { get; set; }
}

public class CashPayment : Payment
{
    public CashPayment(Guid distributeId, Guid invoiceId, int userId, decimal amount, DateTime dateTime) : base(distributeId, invoiceId, userId, amount,dateTime)
    {
    }
}


public class ChequePayment : Payment
{

    public string SerialNumber { get; private set; }
    public int BankId { get; private set; }
    public string BankBranchName { get; set; }
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    public string BankBranchCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string SayddiNumber { get; set; }

    
}
```

These show above.

I use ef-core. I want to use TPH for persistence.

```
 public class Invoice : EntityBase<Guid>, IAggregateRoot<Invoice>
{
    protected List<Payment> _payments = new List<Payment>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Payment> Payments => _payments.AsReadOnly();
}
```

On the other hand, I use the base class for mapping Aggregate roots like this.

```
public abstract class EntityMappingBase<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class,IEntityBase, IAggregateRoot<TEntity>
{

    public abstract void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);
}
```

}

```
   public class InvoiceMapping : EntityMappingBase<Invoice>
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Invoice> builder)
        {
            Initial(builder);


            builder.OwnsMany(a => a.Payments, map =>
            {
                map.Property(i => i.Id)
               .ValueGeneratedNever();
                map.HasKey(i => i.Id);

                map.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("InvoiceId");

                map.UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);


                ToTable(map);
            });

        }
    }
```

But I don't map these classes into The Invoice Class.

Comment: As of the latest at this time EF Core 5.0, [Docs- Owned Entity Types - Current shortcomings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings) say: *"Owned entity types cannot have inheritance hierarchies*"

Comment: Btw, since collections of owned types are stored in separate table(s), why do you need `OwnsMany` / `WithOwner` and not just regular `HasMany` / `WithOne`? I really don't see a benefit of making them owned. Auto include can be configured for regular entities as well, and all other owned entity type behaviors are more like restrictions (cannot query separately etc.) than functionality.

Comment: Yes, But I made a constraint that AggregateRoot only can contribute to the mapping class.

Comment: So what? Create another mapping classes which do not inherit your `EntityMappingBase<TEntity>`. All EF Core needs is `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` with the only constraint being `TEntity : class`

Comment: Of course, I have exactly done this. Thanks for your answer.